# How to establish Wifi communication between Android Phone and Arduino with Wireless Transceiver module (no wifi shield)

Tags: android, arduino, wifi-direct

I have been looking for a solution for establising Wifi Communication between and **Android Phone** and **Arduino with Wireless Transceiver module (*no wifi shield*)**
Need help in

- Android code to establish such a connection.
- Transmit commands to Arduino
- Receive Command execution status from Arduino

**HARDWARE**

1. ESP8266
2. Nano V3.0- Arduino

Circuit Image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9QHm.jpg)

Note: I have already evaluated the pros and cons of using WIfi over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NRF24L01 is not an wifi device. So there is no way you can connect it to your android phone. If you are seeing for any wifi device for connecting to arduino take a look at **ESP8266**

Comment: Dear Krishna Thanks for pointing out the error. Please read Wireless inplace of Wifi.

Comment: Alternatively can we use ESP8266 to connect to Android Smartphone without Wifi Shield to send and received commands?

Comment: yes, you can use it, i have tried it myself @AnuragChauhan

Comment: What i have read on net is that ESP8266 can be directly used without arduino. Can you share the number of output pins on ESP8266? further do you know any cheap voltage regulators which can convert 220V AC to 3.3V DC?

Comment: you can see this link [ESP8266 Datasheet](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf) . and what you are talking about is i think the answer is solid state relay, they wont essentially convert 220V AC to 3.3V DC but would help you in controlling them like to ON or OFF, please have a read on it. And please if you have any extra questions which are off-topic to what you have posted above please consider making them a new question so that others might get benefitted who are searching for answer and mark this as answer @AnuragChauhan

Comment: Thanks Krishna will adhere to the suggessioin. Comming back to the initial question.

Comment: Required sample Android code to establish connection.with ESP8266 
detailing Transmit commands to ESP8266 and how to 
Receive Command execution status from ESP8266

Comment: you can follow this [Link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-the-ESP8266-module/?ALLSTEPS) and this [Link](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=at_commands) and last this [Link](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/wi-fi-module-esp8266-3-connect-to-android-mobile/) link, you will get all the required tutorial and information about what you have asked for @AnuragChauhan

Comment: Thanks Krishna, the support provided is really appreciated. I think I will be able to build upon the directions provided. However my exact requirement was a sample android studio code showing how to send an AT command to the device. Using Telnet screen is not what I had in mind. Thanks Anyway